# convert row to column sql based on pk fk relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have the following two table

**tblPlan**

```
ID  |   Name
------------
1   |   A
2   |   B
3   |   C
```

**tblDetails**

```
ID  |   PlanID  |   R   |   C   |   Type
-----------------------------------------
1   |   1       |   1   |   2   |   X
2   |   1       |   1   |   2   |   M
3   |   1       |   2   |   5   |   L
4   |   2       |   3   |   3   |   X
5   |   2       |   4   |   4   |   L
6   |   3       |   1   |   c   |   X

tblDetails.PlanId(fk) = tblPlan.ID(Pk)
```

Now I want output like the following

```
Plan.ID,Plan.Name Type R  C  Type R  C Type R  C ...

1   A   X  1   2   M   1   2   L   2   5
2   B   X  3   3               L   3   4
3   C   X  1   1
```

based on relation

I want a single row for every plan.how to do this?anyone helps is greatly appreciated?

Comment: Are you asking how to do a join?

Comment: Or do you want one row for every tblPlan row and all the details in different fields on the same row?

Comment: i want one row for every tblPlan row and all the details in different fields in the same row.details table have several row whose PlanID is same as tblPlan ID.
1   A   X  1   2   M   1   2   L   2   5
2   B   X  3   3               L   3   4
3   C   X  1   1

Comment: Would it be OK if you got each detail in a separate row and then joined them up via the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In separate columns by single query is seems not possible, but you can get plan details in comma separated values in single column like this way

```
 select Id, 
        Name,
        STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + [Type] + ',' + CAST(R AS VARCHAR(1)) + ',' + C
                FROM    tblDetails
                WHERE   PlanID = P.Id
                FOR XML PATH (''))
        , 1, 1, '') AS PlanDetail
from    tblPlan P
```

**Output :**

```
Id     Name    PlanDetail
1      A       X,1,2,M,1,2,L,2,5
2      B       X,3,3,L,3,4
3      C       X,1,c
```